# Angular 2 is removing UTM from URL

Tags: angular, google-analytics, utm-tracking

I'm doing work on a site developed with Angular 2. I'm trying to set up UTM campaigns for this site, and I'm running into an issue where the UTM query gets removed from the URL upon page load. This site uses `useHash` in the `RouterModule`, so the URL has the following format: https://examplesite.com/#/home.
When I generate the UTM, I get the following: http://examplesite.com/?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=test_campaign10#/home.
When I visit this UTM link, the UTM gets removed...Does this have something to do with `useHash`? Thanks.

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { NoContentComponent } from './no-content';
import { HomeComponent } from '../pages/home';

export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: '**', component: NoContentComponent },
];
```

Comment: what does mean `UTM`?

Comment: UTM is for tracking campaigns in Google Analytics @RezaRahmati

Comment: Does the page load on a certain Angular route and then redirects to a different route?
Can you show a snippet of the application's route declarations? (At least the route you're entering the app from with the `utm` query param)

Comment: @webdevius Thanks for the reply. It looks like it redirects back to 'home'. I've updated the issue to show an example of how my routes are declared.

Comment: It does have to do with `useHash` configuration.
If you change the placement of the Hash in the genrated UTM links it should be preserved on the initial navigation
`http://examplesite.com/#/?utm_source=.......`

Comment: I read that Google doesn't read any query that comes after a hash though. And I saw other Angular examples that have the query before the hash.

Comment: No, Angular does not remove *any* query parameters. Make sure you have disabled your **adblocker**.

Comment: can u show how you have added the utm tagging in url?